# Aspnet_regsql.exe - Which folder to use?

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-framework-version

I need to enable SQL cache notification on my SQL Server via the command :

`aspnet_regsql.exe -S .. -U sa -P ..`

**SQL server version:**

[image]

**Windows server version :**

[image]

However - When I'm looking for the `aspnet_regsql.exe` file, I found many versions :

[image]

**Question**

How can I **be sure** which version to use? The computer has a 64-bit operating system, but this doesn't mean that SQL Server uses the 64-bit .NET framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your SQL Server installation, if you want to know if that is a 32 or 64 bit installation, use the following T-SQL:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
```

that will give an output like `Developer Edition` or `Developer Edition (64-bit)`.

About your question, I think you have to use the executable `aspnet_regsql.exe` in the directory `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` (if you're using the .NET Framework 4), since yours is a 64-bit OS, as explained in the [MSDN documentation about `aspnet_regsql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')` indeed that was the missing part